# Convert python 2.7 64bit to 32bit Centos6.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos

Hi I have installed python2.7 64bit on a CentOS6.9 machine, and later realize that the program I am suppose to run is 32bit, is there a way to switch the python2.7 from 64bit to 32bit, I have try to rebuild python2.7 to 32bit, but it seems without uninstalling the 64bit python I have no way of getting the 32bit up but

> yum remove python

will removed many dependency which I don't want to, so is there a way to switch ?

Answer (score 1):

First, install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). You can then create a virtual environment by using:

```
virtualenv --python=/path/to/your/32bit_python ~/py32
source ~/py32/bin/activate
```

Now, your system will use this version of python, and `pip` will install to this environment.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183911/how-to-run-specific-architecture-32-64-of-python-in-centos6-when-both-are-inst/183946#183946).

Comment: Hi i tried your solution but it ends up that the system is still searching all the shared object at the old lib path...

Comment: @user1998844 Not sure what the problem could be. From what I've seen. this should do it. Did you make sure to activate it? Possibly install `virtualenvwrapper` too if it helps.